# Return variably sized bitset

Tags: c++, templates, bitset

I was looking around for a way to return a bitset of varied size using a template or something similar. I haven't really had the chance to play around with it too much yet, but I was just curious if someone has ever messed with this before, and has managed to accomplish this.

The goal here is to avoid writing 4 functions for 4 different sizes of bitsets (32, 17, 10, 5). I was thinking I could use some kind of template in order to accomplish this (just placing the template directly on the function itself, not a class implementation or anything like that).

so it would look something like this:

```
template<something SIZE>
     static bitset<SIZE> function(bitset<SIZE>);
```

I'd basically be passing in a bitset of size SIZE and then returning that size bitset back after some stuff is done to it.

I could probably accomplish this with a vector and cast later, but I get the feeling there's some kind of way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here. If anyone has any thoughts, please feel free to let me know. I intend to dig into this a bit later and do some testing, so I'll update this as I find some things out.

Thanks in advance.

-----Edit-----

I've gone ahead and implemented Mark_B's solution, and it appears to work well. If anyone has another implementation I'd be glad to see it, but I'm simply using a template to implement this.

Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: Does the caller know the size at compile time?

Comment: Yes, the caller would know this size at compile time. It's just used as a static function for doing minor modifications to bitsets. In that case, Mark_B's solution seems to be effective, so I'm going to go with that for the time being. If anyone else has another solution that might work better, or might just work differently, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<bool>` is specialized so that quality implementations use just 1 bit per item. That's the closest to a variable length bitset the standard library provides. Other than that, you can just do it yourself, or use the Boost `dynamic_bitset`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing this, but it would require me to rewrite other sections of my code that I've already implemented using a bitset. I guess I could just write a function to convert back and forth, but that would probably lead me to the same problem (requiring me to return a dynamically sized bitset). Converting on the fly would be simple, but I would have to do it multiple times, and I like to be lazy when I know I'm going to write something 10 times in 10 different places.

Answer (score 2):

Something would be `size_t`.

```
template<size_t SIZE>
bitset<SIZE> function(bitset<SIZE>);
```

Comment: I prefer to use `ptrdiff_t`, or just `int`. Using `size_t` helps with a bug in some older versions of g++, though. Not sufficient reason to use it IMHO.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Since the template type of `bitset` is `size_t` can you elaborate on why to not use that?

Comment: I was thinking this would work, but didn't get time to test it out. That makes things very simple. Usually when I use templates, I implement them using classes and typedefs as the arguments, so I guess I just wasn't sure that I could use a size_t as the template type. After testing this method, it seems to work perfectly. Haven't run into any issues so far. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MarkB: `size_t` is there for historical reasons, it's practically impossible to change. But as an unsigned type it clashes with the (current) implicit conversion rules of C++. Unsigned types are good for bit level operations, but the clash means they're ungood for number values. `ptrdiff_t`, the result type for pointer difference, has the same range for all in-practice cases (necessarily), and no such problem. In passing, I'd avoid using multi-character `ALL UPPERCASE` names, especially ones others might use. Those clash with the common convention for macros, and macros don't respect scopes.